# passport.js, express.js - back to the same page after oauth

Tags: javascript, twitter, express, oauth, passport.js

I want users to be navigated to the same page after `OAuth` request to `twitter`. I understand that this only can be done by setting the session variable, but how exactly this should be done?

Currently the routes are configured as follows:

```
// Authentication routes
(function () {
    app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

    app.get('/auth/twitter/done',
        passport.authenticate('twitter', {
            failureRedirect : '/auth/error'
        }),
        function (req, res) {
            res.send('Logged In.');
        });

    app.get('/auth/error', function (req, res) {
        res.send('An error has occured.');
    });
}());
```

I can read the session variable in the route `"/auth/twitter/done"` and redirect to the page it contains. But what is the correct way of setting it?

```
    app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'),
        function (res, req) { res.session.authReturnPage = '...'; });
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `req.session.authReturnPage` before calling `passport.authenticate('twitter')`:

```
app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res) {
    req.session.authReturnPage = req.headers.referer;
    passport.authenticate('twitter');
}
```